# Using a React State object as key to another value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, object

I haven't been able to figure out an efficient solution to my specific problem after trying a bunch on my own, and looking at several questions on Stack Overflow, so hopefully someone can lead me in the right direction.

I am using React.js hooks have a state object which changes state (size and color) based on two select menus and onChange handlers. On state change, in addition to setting the select menus I would like to derive an numerical ID to set for `selectedVariant`, in which the ID comes from different combinations of the `options` state object, regardless of the order in which they were selected. All of the possible combinations like `{color: "Blue", size : "M" } -- mapped to --> 1234` are known, in my control, and can be put in a Map, object or array etc, but I am unsure of the best way to set mapping up and respond to this changing state efficiently. The setup and onChange I created looks like this, and here is a simple codesandbox [linked here](https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-wood-xw29v?file=/src/App.js) which contains additional info to demonstrate and a playground for the below code

```js
const [options, setOptions] = useState({}); // based on this state ...
const [selectedVariant, setSelectedVariant] = useState(null); // how do I derive a value for this?
...
      <select
        value={options.size}
        onChange={e => setOptions({ ...options, size: e.target.value })}
      >
        <option value="S">S</option>
        <option value="M">M</option>
        <option value="L">L</option>
        <option value="XL">XL</option>
      </select>
      <select
        value={options.color}
        onChange={e => setOptions({ ...options, color: e.target.value })}
      >
        <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
        <option value="Gray">Gray</option>
      </select>
...
```

The current state could be `{size : "M", color : "Blue"}` or `{color : "Gray", size : "XL"}` etc. depending on what is currently selected and the order in which the select boxes were populated. However, I now need to derive a variant ID from the currently selected state to know which product variant is selected using the combination of those attributes.

**Examples:** `{size : "M", color : "Blue"}` would derive `1234` from a mapping source and then would be set as `setSelectedVariant(12345)` and become the new `selectedVariant` state.

`{color : "Gray", size : "XL"}` (note: different order but same keys) would derive `5678` from a mapping source and then would be set as `setSelectedVariant(5678)` and become the new `selectedVariant` state.

**Update:**
**Example Mapping:**
Here is a sample mapping object of what could be done to map them in order to correlate a variant to the option values.

```
{
  "variants": [
    {
      "id": 1234,
      "title": "M / Blue",
      "option_values": [
        {
          "name": "Size",
          "value": "M"
        },
        {
          "name": "Color",
          "value": "Blue"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 5678,
      "title": "XL / Gray",
      "option_values": [
        {
          "name": "Size",
          "value": "XL"
        },
        {
          "name": "Color",
          "value": "Gray"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

which would most likely result in having to do something like a js `.find()` each time the state changes in order to grab the variant[n].id to pass to `setSelectedVariant`. Is this the best way to go about it?

Would this be a good use case for [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) 
? I also have looked into javascript [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) which allows you to set an object as a key, but I wasn't able to get it working for this scenario. I am open to suggestions on different ways to think about, but hoping someone can point me to some ideas/resources to help me.

Comment: Can you use an effect that runs when options change? I am not clear how you would translate `{size : "M", color : "Blue"}` to `1234`

Comment: @HMR So, I can definitely run an effect when options change but where I am kind of getting stuck is that even though I know `{size : "M", color : "Blue"}` should translate to `1234` ( and know all combinations) how can I make that an efficient mapping? I mean I could create an array of all of the mappings and iterate over each time options changes but that did not seem super efficient to me and still trying to figure out if thats the best/only way to approach it

Comment: Can you give an example what the translate data looks like to get the `1234` value, you can update the question with only a couple of records?

Comment: @HMR Sure - I updated my answer to reflect a sample mapping in which you potentially could derive the id 1234 by iterating over the `variants` array to find where the `option_values` match the `{size : "M", color : "Blue"}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code takes your variants data and generates data for the selectors and a `variantsByKey` that can be used to look up the id of the variant based on values from the selects.

The `variantsSelects` can be used for the selects and contains an enabled value to prevent non existing combinations such as `Blue / XL`.

Here is the code, I disabled showing the console.logs but you can take the code in a project and play around with it to understand it better.

```js
const data = {
  variants: [
    {
      id: 5,
      title: 'Blue',
      option_values: [
        {
          name: 'Color',
          value: 'Blue',
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 1234,
      title: 'M / Blue',
      option_values: [
        {
          name: 'Size',
          value: 'M',
        },
        {
          name: 'Color',
          value: 'Blue',
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 5678,
      title: 'XL / Gray',
      option_values: [
        {
          name: 'Size',
          value: 'XL',
        },
        {
          name: 'Color',
          value: 'Gray',
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};
const removeKey = (object, key) =>
  Object.entries(object)
    .filter(([k]) => k !== key)
    .reduce((result, [key, value]) => {
      result[key] = value;
      return result;
    }, {});
//special none value
const NONE = 'NONE';
const App = ({ data }) => {
  const [
    selectedVariants,
    setSelectedVariants,
  ] = React.useState({});
  //set the values for dropdowns
  const variants = React.useMemo(
    () =>
      [
        ...data.variants
          .map(({ option_values }) => option_values)
          .flat()
          .reduce(
            (result, { name, value }) =>
              result.set(
                name,
                (result.get(name) || []).concat(value)
              ),
            new Map()
          )
          .entries(),
      ].map(([key, values]) => [key, [...new Set(values)]]),
    [data.variants]
  );
  console.log('variants:', variants);
  const variantsByKey = React.useMemo(
    () =>
      new Map(
        data.variants.map(({ id, option_values }) => [
          variants
            .map(([key]) =>
              option_values.find(({ name }) => name === key)
            )
            .filter((x) => x)
            .map(({ name, value }) => `${name}::${value}`)
            .join('++'),
          id,
        ])
      ),
    [data.variants, variants]
  );
  //selects with enabled value to disable non existant
  //  combinations
  const variantsSelects = React.useMemo(() => {
    const optionGroup = data.variants.map(
      ({ option_values }) =>
        option_values
          .map(({ name, value }) => [name, value])
          .reduce(
            (result, [key, value]) =>
              result.set(key, value),
            new Map()
          )
    );
    const selected = Object.entries(selectedVariants);
    return variants.map(([key, options]) => {
      //selected options munus current option type
      const sel = selected.filter(([k]) => k !== key);
      return [
        key,
        options.map((option) => [
          option,
          optionGroup
            .filter((variant) =>
              sel.every(
                ([key, value]) => variant.get(key) === value
              )
            )
            .some((v) => v.get(key) === option),
        ]),
      ];
    });
  }, [data.variants, selectedVariants, variants]);
  console.log('variants by key', variantsByKey);
  console.log('selects', variantsSelects);
  const [variantId, setVariantId] = React.useState();
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const variantId = variantsByKey.get(
      variants
        .map(([key]) => key)
        .filter((key) => selectedVariants[key])
        .map((key) => `${key}::${selectedVariants[key]}`)
        .join('++')
    );
    setVariantId(variantId);
  }, [selectedVariants, variants, variantsByKey]);
  const changeSelectedVariant = React.useCallback(
    (value, key) =>
      setSelectedVariants((current) =>
        value !== NONE
          ? {
              ...current,
              [key]: value,
            }
          : removeKey(current, key)
      ),
    []
  );
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>variant id: {variantId}</h3>
      {variantsSelects.map(([key, values]) => (
        <label key={key}>
          {key}
          <select
            value={selectedVariants[key]}
            onChange={(e) =>
              changeSelectedVariant(e.target.value, key)
            }
          >
            <option value={NONE}>Select option</option>
            {values.map(([value, enabled]) => (
              <option
                value={value}
                name={key}
                key={value}
                disabled={!enabled}
              >
                {value}
              </option>
            ))}
          </select>
        </label>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <App data={data} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: awesome, just ran through the code in my editor. Thank you for your help... I appreciate it!

Comment: @mcdev Updated answer, non existing combinations are not possible anymore.